# Java Calendar Class Not returning May-31

Tags: java

My Program Java Calendar class is set to May-31

When I tried to get maximum no of days in May month, its returning 31. it's Ok.

```
int days = c.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
System.out.println("Month:" + days);
```

But when i am trying to get `Calendar.MONTH` and `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH`

it is always returning June-1

Comment: Can you update your question with more details, ideally the actual code that doesn't work for you?

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `java.text.SimpleDateFormat` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [*java.time*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 and later. See [*Tutorial* by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 4):

Unlike all other Calendar fields, months are zero-based; January=0, February=1, etc. This means May is month number *4*, not 5.

When you set the month to 5 and day to 31, you're trying to set it to *June* 31, which it coverts to *July* 1, there being only 30 days in June.

Comment: Since the code snippet prints 31, this is hardly the explanation of the observed behaviour. As you say, there are only 30 days in June.

Answer (score 0):

`getActualMaximum()` returns the maximum value of the field.

- `getActualMaximum(Calender.DAY_OF_MONTH)` returns 31, the maximum amount of days in a month
- `getActualMaximum(Calender.DAY_OF_WEEK)` will return 7, the maximum amount of days in a week

`Calendar.MONTH` and `Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH` are not automatically set to the date, so return their default values, June 1

Try

```
 Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
```

That should set it to today's date.

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

Use the modern *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy date-time classes.

```
YearMonth.from( 
    LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MAY , 31 ) 
).lengthOfMonth()
```

> 31

```
LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MAY , 31 ) 
         .getMonthValue()
```

> 5

```
LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MAY , 31 ) 
         .getYear()
```

> 2018

## java.time

Your Question does not provide enough detail to diagnose the issue. But the question is moot, with a better alternative approach available now.

The troublesome `Calendar` class is now legacy, replaced by the java.time classes.

The modern approach to representing a month uses the [`YearMonth`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html) class.

```
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.of( 2018 , Month.MAY ) ;
```

Or get a `YearMonth` from a date, a `LocalDate` object.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2018 , Month.MAY , 31 ) ;
YearMonth ym = YearMonth.from( ld ) ;
```

Interrogate for the [length of the month](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/YearMonth.html#lengthOfMonth--).

```
int lengthOfMonth = ym.lengthOfMonth() ;
```

> 31

The `LocalDate` can give you numbers for its day-of-month and its year.

```
int dayOfMonth = ld.getMonthValue() ;
int year = ld.getYear() ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Dear Down-Voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote.

Answer (score -1):

You just have to add one line after creating instance of `Calendar()`.

For example:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.clear();
```

it will work.